# SaveFileDialog removes extension from set filename

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the app below. I modified it slightly for easier testing for readers here. I notice that when I set the Filename with an extension, e.g. test.txt, the txt extension is removed by the dialog. However I want users to be able to specify an extension, and more importantly I want to be able to set the extension. One way to hack it in I figure is to modify the filter based on the extension I have. Is this the only way?

I am using VS 2010 Express.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;
namespace SpeedDating
{
    partial class Program
    {
         [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Form form = new Form();
            form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
            form.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            form.TopMost = true;
            form.Show();

            string filename = "test.txt";
            string ext = filename.Substring(filename.LastIndexOf('.'));
            SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog();
            dialog.Title = "SpeedDating App";
            dialog.RestoreDirectory = true;
            dialog.CheckFileExists = false;
            dialog.CheckPathExists = false;
            dialog.SupportMultiDottedExtensions = true;
            dialog.AddExtension = false;
            dialog.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*";
            dialog.FileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ext;

            DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK && dialog.FileName != "")
            {
                try
                {
                    FileStream outfs = File.Create(dialog.FileName);
                    FileStream infs = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open);
                    infs.CopyTo(outfs);
                    infs.Close();
                    outfs.Close();

                    MessageBox.Show(form, "Copied file.");
                }
                catch (NotSupportedException ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(form, "Probably removed the original file.");
                }
            }
            else if (result != DialogResult.Cancel)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(form, "No path found to write to.");
            }

            form.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I copied your code in and only changed the references to "form" in the messageboxes.  It works fine for me.  I always get the exact file I key into the dialog.

Comment: Not that I think it is causing any problems, but what is the purpose of the "form" object anyhow?  It's empty and does nothing.  You don't _have_ to anchor your MessageBoxes you know.

Comment: On my system, I found that the dialog follows whatever is set by the user at operating system level.  If extensions are hidden in File Explorer then they will also be hidden in the dialog, and the opposite was true as well.

Comment: @Idle_Mind Good catch...this might be the real reason.  I see that too.  So in reality, `dialog.FileName` has the right filepath, OP is just not seeing it perhaps because of this setting.  Could be.

Comment: @DonBoitnott I didn't have an anchor at first but it was causing problems with focusing.

Comment: @RobotRock This is on Form already, right?  So instead of `form` use `this`.

Comment: @DonBoitnott Ah no, it's not a form. That's not meant to be there (the inheritance).

Comment: @Idle_Mind It happens with every file extension.

Comment: Did you go into **File Explorer** and turn OFF the "hide file extensions" option?  Does that cause the dialog to then show your desired extension?

Comment: @Idle_Mind, yes, by default, if "File name extensions" is checked in Explorer then `Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog` respects the extension in the `FileName` property, otherwise it strips out the extension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> and more importantly I want to be able to set the extension

You can set the **.DefaultExt()**, **.AddExtension()**, **.Filter()**, and **.FilterIndex()** properties:

```
        string filename = "test.xyz";

        SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog();
        dialog.Title = "SpeedDating App";
        dialog.RestoreDirectory = true;
        dialog.CheckFileExists = false;
        dialog.CheckPathExists = false;
        dialog.SupportMultiDottedExtensions = true;
        dialog.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*";

        dialog.DefaultExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(filename);
        if (dialog.DefaultExt.Length > 0)
        {
            dialog.AddExtension = true;
            dialog.Filter = dialog.DefaultExt + " files (*." + dialog.DefaultExt + ")|*." + dialog.DefaultExt + "|" + dialog.Filter;
            dialog.FilterIndex = 0;
        }

        dialog.FileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");

        DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK && dialog.FileName != "")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dialog.FileName);
        }
```

*Note that if the option to display "File Extensions" is turned OFF in File Explorer, then the dialog will also hide the extension...**BUT** the above setup will add the set extension to the .FileName() value returned by the dialog.